# In a Python functions, when should a parameter be passed as a prefix , and when inside a function

Tags: python

Sometimes in list functions, we pass parameters as prefix and sometimes inside. Why do we do that? Is there any rule that determines the position?

Example :

```
numbers = [1, 3, 4, 2] 
 
#Sorting list, the parameters are passed as prefix  
numbers.sort() 
 
#Sum list, the parameters are passed inside  
sum(numbers)
```

Comment: sort is a method of the object numbers.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel, it's actually a method of the `list` class.  You can sort objects other than numbers.

Comment: yep and `sum` is a func, see func vs method in python

Comment: Nope. It's an instance method. A class method is another thing altogether.

Comment: Well, yes.  I meant that it’s a method provided by the list class.  It’s not a method of integers.

Comment: I never said it was a method of integers. I said it was a method of the object numbers, which is what the OP named his variable.

Comment: @DanielWalker , since the OP named his variable `numbers`, you had this idea that I believed sorting was only for integers?

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is it depends on how the function was implemented.  In the case of `list.sort`, that is a method created in the definition of the `list` class and thus is an attribute that all lists possess.

`sum`, on the other hand, is a global function and not a method attached to a particular class.

As for the rationale behind the design decision, a lot of it comes down to how Python's class hierarchy is arranged.

Take `sum`, for example.  `sum` can take any iterable as an argument and not just a list.  In order to implement the function as a method of iterables in general, there would have to be a base `Iterable` class from which all iterable subclasses (e.g., `list`, `tuple`, `generator`) would inherit.

However, there is no `Iterable` base class.  Instead, any object is considered iterable if it has an `__iter__` method which returns an iterator.  So, there can't be one class above all iterable classes from which to inherit a `.sum` method.